# sending notification from service using background thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-notifications

This is my service code

```
public class MyService extends Service {
NotificationManager NM;
ServerSocket serversocket=null;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("","startcommand is called");



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


private final IBinder binder=new MyBinder();



//this use for binding with activity
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}



//this class used by the Client to access the service
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService(){
            return MyService.this;
        }
}






public void notify(){


    Notification notify=new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,"Service is created",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("json","the notification method");
    PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getApplicationContext(),0, i,0);
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(this,"subject","body",pending);
    NM.notify(0, notify);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ServerConnection serverConnection=new ServerConnection();
    serverConnection.execute();

}





public class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DataInputStream dataInputStream;

        try {
            serversocket = new ServerSocket(9100);
            while(true){

                Log.i("aa", "Service is listening to port");
                Socket socket =   serversocket.accept();


             NM = (NotificationManager)     getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               publishProgress("ok");





            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        notify();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }





}
```

}

I don't if this it is ok to use Asynctask in service but anyway whenever i call notify() which send notification i got an error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
        at com.example.com.service.MyService.notify(MyService.java:76)
        at com.example.com.service.MyService$ServerConnection.onProgressUpdate(MyService.java:135)
        at com.example.com.service.MyService$ServerConnection.onProgressUpdate(MyService.java:95)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the notify() function which sends notification works fine if a used it in onStartCommand or anywhere except in the background thread.

what i am trying to do is whenever i receive some data using serversocket i want to send a notification to the user which is not working .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this 2 line-

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   //// other lines
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(this,"subject","body",pending);
```

here, `this` means the asynctask when you are calling the method from asynctask, right? you should try replacing it with `MyService.this`.

Comment: thx it worked just one more question how can i send a message from service to activity in case it is not closed so that i don't send notification to application in case it is already opened

Comment: please don't get me wrong, you should ask a separate question for this. share the question url here. We will try to help you regarding that problem. This is necessary so that next time someone faces the same problem, they would be able to get the answer. :)